# My question was posted twice

Tags: bug, asking-questions

Active question: [Who is the youngest Starfleet Admiral?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/243735/12857)

Unintended duplicate post, now deleted: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/243734/12857

I typed out my question and clicked the button to post it. The page scrolled to the top and I got the "Our automated system checked for ways to improve your question and found none" message. I clicked again to post the question and closed the tab.

An hour later I came back to check if I'd gotten any answers and found that my question had been posted twice.

At no point did I copy/paste the contents of my question or click the "ask question" button again. I did open a few other SFF tabs to conduct research for my question and check for potential duplicates.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but the same thing happened [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339640/user-managed-to-post-a-question-twice-within-the-same-second-of-each-other) and some thing similar [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126952/my-answer-was-posted-twice-despite-the-rate-limit-for-users-with-less-than-125)

Comment: They were posted in the same second of each other, presumably the system just borked and got confused. I don't think it's anything you did and should be nothing to worry about.

Comment: Ah, cross-site dupe then.

Comment: This site might help you; https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Might also be a case of mouse double clicking, maybe?

Comment: @Clockwork Pretty sure I didn't, and even if I did, that's still a bug in the site. Button should disable after it receives the first click.

Comment: Nah, I mean, sometimes, when a mouse driver is glitchy or the mouse has been used for too long, I had some case where I wanted to select a folder on my computer, and it opened it instead, because even a simple click caused it to click twice.

Comment: [Comment duplication problem has been duplicated, again! Bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314689/303080) discussed twinning of comments, not posts, but the underlying cause may be similar. In my case it generally occurred with a WiFi connection or otherwise slow internet situations, and I think it had to do with something not hearing "got it" soon enough to something was sent again (e.g. a "post this" message)